# SQL Query SELECT table that sum all values where two others are equal

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following table ("Have").
What would be a proper way to SELECT a table where you sum the value of C where A and B are equal. So that you get the result displayed in "Want".

[image]

Comment: look up `group by`.

Comment: it was an error. now fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [group by then sum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

```
select A, B, sum(c) from your_table group by A, B
```